# Replace blocks of numbers: </2645>

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a file in Notepad++ that was converted from a PDF.
I've managed to sanitise loads of nasty glitches with regex but this one escapes me.
Blocks of numbers like these:

```
</2478><2479>
</2517><2518>
</2605><2606>
</2518>
</2645>
```

Thousands of 'em. They look like some "switch on" - "switch off" commands.
All I want to do is delete them completely. But how do I search for blocks that start with a "<"? I know this is a special character in regex but even escaping it with a backslash (and even with two), Notepad++ doesn't find them.

What am I doing wrong?

@Toto and LPChip
Thanks for the responses.

Here's a sample of the German text (names changed):

```
http://www.XXXXX-service.com/
<2339>Seite </2339><2343/><2346> von 150</2346>
<2355>Seite </2355><2359/><2362> von 150</2362>
<2368>JOHN SMITH Engineering GmbH - </2368><2369>www.XXXXX-service.com</2369>
http://www.XXXXX-service.com/
<2381>Seite </2381><2385/><2388> von 150</2388>
<2394>JOHN SMITH Engineering GmbH - </2394><2395>www.XXXXX-service.com</2395>
http://www.XXXXX-service.com/
<2407>JOHN SMITH Engineering GmbH - </2407><2408>www.XXXXX-service.com</2408>
http://www.XXXXX-service.com/
Seite 89 von 150
<2426>Seite </2426><2430/><2433> von 150</2433>
```

"Seite" = Page, "von" = of. So these are probably fields taken over from the original PDF. Since the final English version will have to be completely reformatted anyway, I can remove these.

The document is over 300 pages in Word, around 39,000 words.

But spread around the document are around 5000 of these <1234> items. None of them contain information vital to the understanding of the sentence. Here's a good one:

```
<4321>Aufnahme des neuen Hilfsaggregats Frequenzumrichter Siemens Sinamic G120C (Kapitel </4321><4337>9</4337><4343> dieses Berichts)</4343>
```

It's a note explaining that the Siemens frequency converter has been added to the report and refers to Chapter 9 (Kapitel 9). So the chapter number is in clear text.

That is to say, all these `<1234>` candidates can go.

e.g.

```
Aufnahme des neuen Hilfsaggregats Frequenzumrichter Siemens Sinamic G120C (Kapitel 9 dieses Berichts)
```

I had Reg Ex activated.

AH

@Toto
That reg ex solution looks very promising. I'll give it a run later this week, when I get a moment. But it looks to me as if that solves the issue. I've used reg ex on and off before but there a couple of commands in your answer that I've never used as yet. You live and learn. Many thanks!
AH

UPDATE...Wednesday 25th...
[Screenshot of F&R results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIiNx.png)

Excellent - thanks very much to all involved!

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1813386/edit) and add sample text and expected result. `<` is not a special char for regex in Notepad++

Comment: Have you selected `Regular Expression` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `</?\d+/?>`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<           # less than sign
/?          # optional slash
\d+         # 1 or more digits
/?          # optional slash
>           # greater than sign
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The regex you can use is `^<.+>$`
See below for example:
[image]

Comment: Assuming that the file has these blocks on one line with nothing in front or behind is not smart. Therefor it is likely that this will fail because ^and $ are used which means start and end of line. I would not be surprised if OP is looking at `<2478>text</2478><2479>text</2479>`

Comment: @LPChip, I just use the exact input of OP. I am not in his/her mind to know what exactly is the source text :)